# Equation of coupled springs : where does this potential come from?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, spring, coupled-oscillators, normal-modes

In [this document](https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/wheeler/documents/Sophmore%20Class%20Notes%202007/Chapter%204.pdf), we try to derive the equation of two coupled springs as in this picture.

[image]

At the bottom of the page 2, they say : it would be more efficient to introduce the potential energy function $$U(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{2}k_1x_1^2+\frac{1}{2}K(x_2-x_2)^2+\frac{1}{2}k_2x_2^2,$$
and compute $F_1^{net}=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_1}$ and $F_2^{net}=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial x_2}.$

Where does this function come from ? God gave it ?

Comment: Pretty sure that it should be $\frac{1}{2} K (x_2 - x_1)^2$, not $\frac{1}{2} K (x_2 - x_2)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

You remember that if a string of constant $k$ is deformed $x$ its potential energy can be written as

$$
U(x) = \frac{1}{2}k x^2 \tag{1}
$$

Now you have three of them, $k_1$ is deformed by a quantity $x_1$, $k_2$ by $x_2$. The tricky one is $K$, but actually if you look at the diagram you will realize that it is deformed by $x_2 - x_1$, so the total energy is

$$
U(x_1, x_2) = U_{k_1} + U_{K} + U_{k_2} = \frac{1}{2}k_1 x_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}K (x_2 - x_1)^2 + \frac{1}{2}k_2 x_2^2 \tag{2}
$$

No god, sorry